# Do I need to add buffers when creating a 3-input NAND gate from 2-input NANDS because of propagation delays?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates

I'm seeing that a 3-input NAND gate is made up of 3 2-input NANDS. However, the first 2 input has to go through 3 levels of gates, while the third input only need to go through 1-level of gate
[image]

In real circuits, does this mean I need to add buffers in-between the third input so that the signals would reach the end at the same time, or does it not matter? something like this:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can add buffers, but in a good (i.e. robust) logic design you should not need them because you should not be depending on the difference in delays between the different inputs of your NAND gate. Note that there is no guarantee that the delays of the buffers you use match the NAND's delays.

If you have a synchronous logic design, then as long as the total prop delay through your combinational logic is less than a clock cycle, 'balancing' the NAND delays should not matter.

There are possibly some cases where it may have an effect. It is possible that some inputs are known to arrive with a delay w.r.t. the inputs, and so is possible that the output does have some unnecessary (temporary) transitions. These waste power.

Note also that it is possible (and usually done this way) to build a compact 3- (or n-) input CMOS NAND gate with 6 (2*n) transistors.

Comment: Awesome!. Thanks for the response. I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation points to upvote.